# TestNG listener, how to get the singleton use by the tests

Tags: parallel-processing, testng

We use the TestNG listener feature to report the results of our tests in an external tool. It works fine.

But now, we want to add an information contained by a singleton (a ThreadLocal webdriver). Our test campaign is run in parallel, so we have multiple instance of our singleton.

How can we in the method onSuccess for instance get the correct singleton and so report the correct information?

Edit: code sample

```java
public class QTestWrapper implements ISuiteListener, ITestListener {
...
    @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    String sessionId = MyDriver.getSessionId();
    // do my job with this session id
  }
...
}


public final class MyDriver {


  private static final ThreadLocal<MyDriver> MY_DRIVER =
      ThreadLocal.withInitial(MyDriver::buildDriver);

  private WebDriver driver;

  private MyDriver(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  public static MyDriver getDriver() {
    return MY_DRIVER.get();
  }

  private static MyDriver buildDriver() {
    URL remoteAddress = getHubAddress();
    DesiredCapabilities caps = buildCapabilities();
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress, caps);
    return new MyDriver(driver);
  }

  public static String getSessionId() {
    String sessionId = null;
    MyDriver driver = MY_DRIVER.get();
    if (driver != null && driver.getWrappedDriver() != null) {
      WebDriver wrappedDriver = driver.getWrappedDriver();
      sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) wrappedDriver).getSessionId().toString();
    }
    return sessionId;
  }

  public WebDriver getWrappedDriver() {
    return driver;
  }


}

public class TestLogin {

  @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public void die() {
    StickyDriver.quit();
  }

  @Test(description = "Check that a user can login with a Manager profile.")
  public void loginAsManager() {
    Actor actor = new Actor("foo");
    String userName = actor.openBrowserAndLogin().getUserName();
    assertThat(userName).isEqualTo("foo");
  }

}


public class Actor {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

  private final MyDriver driver;
  private User user;

  public Actor(String userName) {
    user = User.getUser(userName);
    driver = MyDriver.getDriver();
  }


  public Actor(User user) {
    this.user = Objects.requireNonNull(user);
    driver = MyDriver.getDriver();
  }

  public HomePage openBrowserAndLogin() {
    openBrowser();
    return login();
  }

  public HomePage login() {
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.getUserNameField().setValue(user.getUsername());
    loginPage.getPasswordField().setValue(user.getPassword());
    return loginPage.login();
  }

  private void openBrowser() {
    String url = EnvironmentHelper.getUrl();
    WebDriver webDriver = driver.getWrappedDriver();
    webDriver.get(url);
    try {
      new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 60).until(AjaxExpectedConditions.callsHaveCompleted());
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
      closeBrowser();
      throw ex;
    }
  }

  public void closeBrowser() {
    MyDriver.quit();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us what your code looks like (test class, listener and the singleton that you are referring to)

Comment: I've edited my message.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG does not guarantee that the `@Test` and `onSuccess()` will be executed in the same thread.

That assurance is only provided when you work with `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` implementation.

So please change your implementation to do the following :

- Have your class `QTestWrapper` implement `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener`
- within the `afterInvocation()` of `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` check if the method that got executed was a `@Test` method and if its status was a pass, and if it passed you move your logic within `onSuccess()` into it.

Comment: Thx for this great tips. One last question. If I assign a value to a class member within afterInvocation, can I be sure to get the same value (so same thread) in onTestSuccess? Or I will still met the thread issue?

Comment: Same thread guarantee is provided by TestNG only for `beforeInvocation() > @Test > afterInvocation()`. So outside of these 3 methods, you should not rely on threadlocal specific data when building implementations.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.